# Subtract a reference image from a photographed map

Tags: arcgis-desktop

[image]For an analysis of the use of hand-drawn glyphs (shading, circling, diagrams) in a GIS, I have a set of printed maps of the same area, embellished with participants' pencil and pen marks.

I would like to scan or photograph these maps and then extract the glyphs as shapefiles. A diagram of this schema/workflow is shown above. My printed maps have georeferencing features (gridlines).

What is the best workflow to both georeference the glyphs, and subtract the reference map leaving the glyphs themselves as shapefiles? (The shapefiles would then be imported into ArcGIS Pro).

Comment: Due to the poor image quality I cannot tell if the map on the far left ( I assumed the map that has been sketched on) has any reference information such as grid lines that can be georeferenced?

Comment: Edited for clarity. The map in the image is not mine, but taken from a similar project. Unfortunately the exact details of how the shapefiles were extracted was unclear.

Comment: Do you have access to any other graphics software? Have you looked into ArcScan? There is also a raster tracing tool In ArcMap that works well, but it has been years.